# Understanding fdisk -l output on a virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, fdisk

I installed lubuntu on VirtualBox and allocated 10Gb fixed storage. Later, I made a copy of the machine and allocated dynamic storage of 20GB. I checked `fdisk` to see if it worked, but I don't completely understand the output:

```
sudo fdisk -l 

    Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x759f6334

       Device  Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size  Id   Type
    /dev/sda1  *      2048  20969471  20967424   10G  83  Linux
```

It seems there is 20GB overall, but only 10GB is available to the root partition? If so, how do I expand it?

Comment: Allocating a larger disc does not automatically resizes the created partitions on it. Download a GParted ISO, mount it to the VM, boot it and increase the root partition size.

Comment: This worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

To resize a partition with `fdisk`, you simply delete and recreate a partition entry with the same start (in your case LBA `2048`) and a new end (e.g. LBA `41943039`, although I would suggest something like `41943299` even if you want to use the whole disk, just in case you spontaneously convert the partition table to GPT someday).

If you are using a recent version of `fdisk` in `util-linux`, it will asks whether you want to remove the filesystem signature when you recreate the partition entry. Make sure you say **N for No**.

Note that partition resized doesn't mean filesystem resized. Use whichever utility **that is specific to the filesystem on the partition** to resize the filesystem (e.g. `resize2fs`, `resize.f2fs`, `btrfs filesystem resize`...). Check its man page to see its options and whether you can extend "online" (i.e. with the filesystem mounted).

The filesystem type can be checked with `lsblk -f` or `blkid`.

Comment: I tried the suggestion in the comment and it worked. Thanks